# Get Dynamic Index of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I've created an SQL Query that orders all the rows of a table by a specific way.

**Q:** How can I get the row number (index?) of a certain row in such a dynamically created list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with xth row number?  If you just want a row index, use `row_number() over (order by field1, field2, ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Row_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <your criteria>) as RowIndex, other fields
FROM MyTable
```

**Update**:

To add this as a field, you can do:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Indexfield = X.RowIndex
FROM MyTable T
INNER JOIN (SELECT Row_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <your criteria>) as RowIndex, other fields
            FROM MyTable) as X
    ON X.<field> = T.<Field>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work until I've added parentheses to ROW_NUMBER (-> ROW_NUMBER()). Thanks. How would I go about looping through the rows of the list and, for example, give this new index as a value to a column of that row?

Comment: @Acidic - see edit.  I think update syntax is valid but you may need to change the order

Comment: What does `FROM MyTable T` supposed to mean? I cannot seem to understand it or make it work. Is it an attempt to pass reference to the table to a variable T?

Comment: It's pseudocode.  you need to, you know, put in real table and field names.